# HTTP conversation is not persistent

Tags: java, http

I need to build a Java server where the client sends an HTTP request, the server sends an HTTP response, the client sends another HTTP request, and the server sends a final response. However, after the server sends the first response to the request, the connection times out. I realized that the client isn't even reading my response until I close the input stream, but this ends the conversation prematurely. Here is the run method for my class ServerThread, which extends Thread.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        l.add(index, serv.accept());
        new ServerThread(serv, l, index + 1).start();
        Socket socket = (Socket)l.get(index);
        index++;
        while(true) {
            while(socket.getInputStream().available() == 0) {}

            while(socket.getInputStream().available() > 0)
                System.out.print((char)socket.getInputStream().read());

            BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            b.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n" +
                    "Connection: keep-alive");
            b.flush();
            //b.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Basically, this code accepts a client and blocks until there is information in the input stream. After there is information, it prints out the request and writes a 200 OK response to the client regardless of the request and keep the connection alive. When I comment out the b.close() call, the conversation hangs, but as soon as I stop the server, the client reads the response. How do I get around this?

Comment: first of all, we need to see some code..

Comment: @MajidL what kind of code do you expect?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Code the reproduces the issue.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza so you're able to answer his question as it is now? (without any code that is).

Comment: Looks like you're reinventing the wheel by doing it all with low-level socket calls.  Why not use an HTTP library and make your life easier?

Comment: @ke4ktz It's a really simple conversation, so I thought that using a library would be unnecessary.

Comment: @ke4ktz Plus doing things low-level builds character. :)

Comment: Shouldn't you use ServerSocket? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

Comment: @STM serv is my ServerSocket.

Comment: @STM the Socket represents the client, and both the input and output stream belong to the client.

Comment: Then why do you write the "200" response on the client Socket?

Comment: @STM Not really sure what you're asking... I'm writing the response to the client's output stream.

Comment: @MajidL the problem is not about code, it is about design. The server should be designed to support a session for every client that connects to the server, like a basic http server. Looks like OP didn't have this in mind, so regardless the piece of code OP can provide, there's no way to help him/her by code, just by advices about how to implement it. The implementation would be too broad, or you could ease yourself by using a lightweight server like jetty embedded in your app.

Comment: @user3704983 HTTP is **NOT** a simple conversation! Plus, as you get more experience you learn not to reinvent what's already been done...especially when the library is free to use.  The Apache HttpComponents library makes this process easy to implement and more tolerant to transient conditions.